# What are the practical reasons to use the "out" keyword

Tags: c#

I have written a utility function:

```
public static void SerializeErrorMessage(int ErrorCode, string ErrorMessage, out byte[] Buffer)
{
    object ErrorJson = new { ErrorCode, ErrorMessage };
    string Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ErrorJson);     
    Buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Serialized);
}
```

I'm wondering why I should/shouldn't have written it like this instead:

```
public static byte[] SerializeErrorMessage(int ErrorCode, string ErrorMessage)
{
    object ErrorJson = new { ErrorCode, ErrorMessage };
    string Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ErrorJson);     
    byte[] Buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Serialized);
    return Buffer;
}
```

Is it just a matter of personal preference? Is the first function more performant than the second function?

Comment: in that instance I would say it's preference. It's often used as a way to 'return' multiple values

Comment: Think about `public static bool TrySerializeErrorMessage()` method instead to see a usage of `out` keyword ;).

Comment: See all the try parse methods [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The out keyword is used when more than one value from a function needs to be returned, without wrapping the values in an object.

e.g. `Integer.TryParse`, has both a return value (bool if parse was successful), and an out parameter that returns the value if the parsing was successful.

In your case, there is no difference